# "No Go files in..." error when i use go with docker compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I installed Go on Ubuntu 16.04. This is my GOPATH=/home/{username}/work.

I created a project into /home/{username}/work/src.

This is my project folder hierarchy.

```
project-name
   services
       configuration
           api
               main.go
           Dockerfile
       bff
           api
               main.go
           Dockerfile
   docker-compose.yml
   favicon.ico
   README.md
```

I can build and run with my dockerfile but I can't build and up with docker-compose.

I couldn't find any solution.

Configuration service dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.11.1-alpine3.8 as builder

RUN apk update && apk add git && go get gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/project-name/services/configuration
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0
RUN GOOS=linux
ADD . /go/src/project-name/services/configuration
ENV GOPATH /go
WORKDIR /go/src/project-name/services/configuration/api
RUN go get
RUN go build

FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add curl

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY --from=builder /go/src/project-name/services/configuration/api/ /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/api
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/api"]
```

It works with dockerfile.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
   bff:
      image: project-name/bff:${TAG:-latest}
      build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: services/bff/Dockerfile
      ports:
          - "5000:5000"
      container_name: bff 
      depends_on:
         - configuration

   configuration:
       image: project-name/configuration:${TAG:-latest}
       build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: services/configuration/Dockerfile    
       ports:
            - "5001:5001"
       container_name: configuration
```

It didn't work.

When the “run go get” command runs, it gives an error, the error is:

```
 can't load package: package project-name/services/configuration/api: no Go files in /go/src/project-name/services/configuration/api
 ERROR: Service 'configuration' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go get' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: And what is the contents of your `lenitivo-server/services/configuration/api` directory?

Comment: @Flimzy There is a only one file which is main.go

Comment: What happens if you issue the command `docker make ./services/configuration/Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, you say

```
ADD . /go/src/project-name/services/configuration
```

which expects the build context directory on the host to contain the source files.  But your `docker-compose.yml` file says

```
build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: services/configuration/Dockerfile
```

where the context directory is the root of your source control tree, not the specific Go source directory you're trying to build.  If you change this to

```
build:
    context: services/configuration
    # Default value of "dockerfile: Dockerfile" will be right
```

it will likely work better.

In plain Docker commands, your current `docker-compose.yml` file says the equivalent of

```
cd $GOPATH/src/project-name
docker build -f services/configuration/Dockerfile .
```

But you're probably actually running

```
cd $GOPATH/src/project-name/services/configuration
docker build .
```

and what directory is the current directory matters.

Comment: I understand, when i changed with "context: services/configuration", it worked ! You' re also right. I runned "cd $GOPATH/src/project-name/services/configuration docker build ." Thanks for your helping.

Comment: @David Maze Can you please also review this question, This is something releated to golang with a bit same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74822708/no-go-files-in-when-on-making-golang-deb-in-gitlab-ci-cd