# no Go files in ... when on making golang deb in gitlab-ci/cd

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

This is something regarding golang, code of which I am using in gitlab-ci.yml file.
This is the error which I am getting `no Go files in /builds/release_management` as shown:

```
$ pwd
/builds/release_management
$ echo $BasePathForBinaryFile1
cmd/main_1/
$ ls
COPYING
DebPackageGitLabDocker
README.md
cmd
deb-build
ermbuild
go.mod
publishToRemote.sh
usr
working_gitlab-ci_ableToCreateDebPackageWithNoBinary.yml
$ echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$BasePathForBinaryFile1
/builds/release_management/cmd/main_1/
$ GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o $BinaryName1 $BasePathForBinaryFile1
no Go files in /builds/release_management
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here is the code of my job

```
variables:
  GOOS: linux
  GOARCH: amd64
  TagName: 1.0.71
  DebFileName: $TagName
  BasePathForBinaryFile1: cmd/main_1/
  BinaryName: main1
  BasePathForBinaryFile2: cmd/main_2/
  BinaryName: main2

build_binary:
  stage: build
  image: golang:latest
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  script:
    - cd cmd/main_1
    - GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o $BinaryName1 $BasePathForBinaryFile1
#    - GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o $BinaryName1 $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$BasePathForBinaryFile1
```

Please note: I have also tried by giving `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/$BasePathForBinaryFile1` and that is also not working.

While, this works when I am doing cd first then building it from current using dot(.)

```
variables:
  GOOS: linux
  GOARCH: amd64
  TagName: 1.0.71
  DebFileName: $TagName
  BasePathForBinaryFile1: cmd/main_1/
  BinaryName: main1
  BasePathForBinaryFile2: cmd/main_2/
  BinaryName: main2

build_binary:
  stage: build
  image: golang:latest
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  script:
    - cd cmd/main_1
    - GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o $BinaryName .
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Any idea what thing should I fix to fix this golang error?

**Edit 1:** Also, when doing `cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$BasePathForBinaryFile` and then `ls` it is not going into that directory and still showing content of base directory only:

```
$ echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$BasePathForBinaryFile1
/builds/SugarBox/edge_release_management/cmd/main_1/
$ cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$BasePathForBinaryFile
$ ls
COPYING
DebPackageGitLabDocker
README.md
cmd
deb-build
ermbuild
go.mod
publishToRemote.sh
usr
working_gitlab-ci_ableToCreateDebPackageWithNoBinary.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. There is no `BinaryName1` in your config so

```
GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o $BinaryName1 $BasePathForBinaryFile1
```

Becomes

```
GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o cmd/main_1/
```

and the source files are expected in current dir, while they are not there. You need to fix config to have `BinaryName1` and `BinaryName2` instead of having `BinaryName` twice.

2. You need to specify src dir as `./cmd/main_1/`.
3. In `Edit 1` part `cd` doesn't work because the env name is incorrect it should be `$BasePathForBinaryFile1` but it is `$BasePathForBinaryFile`.